# How to implement ThreadPool with a async function?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I would like to know how to deal with execute a map_async with a async function.

I've tried with this code, but doesn't wait to the results:

```
def execute_pool_threading_async(number_of_threads, async_function, params):
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=number_of_threads)
    results = pool.map_async(async_function, params)
    results.wait()
    return results
```

I expect the output in results variable.

UPDATE:
This is a wrapper for python 3.6:

```
import asyncio
# from multiprocess.pool import ThreadPool # 3.7
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

async def sleep(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)

    return t


def process_sleep(t):
    #return asyncio.run(sleep(t)) # 3.7
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(sleep(t)))


def main():

    with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(process_sleep, range(1, 5))

    print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But it doesn't work:
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'.

Comment: I think `return results.get()` would do what you want.

Comment: @martineau with .get() it returns a list of a coroutines

Comment: You may need to do a `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` before the `return` — I don't the the `results.wait()` is needed in that case. If you provide some sort of [mcve], then I could verify a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a wrapper sync function which will call the async function by using `asyncio.run` function. Btw, no need to use `pool.map_async` if you wait for results anyway, just use `pool.map` instead. Here is a working example:

```
import asyncio
from multiprocess.pool import ThreadPool


async def sleep(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)

    return t


def process_sleep(t):
    return asyncio.run(sleep(t))


def main():

    with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(process_sleep, range(1, 5))

    print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**UPDATE**

Yep, you're right, I didn't mention the above code is for Python 3.7. Sorry ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ This version works for 3.6:

```
import asyncio
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


async def sleep(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)

    return t


def process_sleep(t):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    return loop.run_until_complete(sleep(t))


def main():

    with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(process_sleep, range(1, 5))

    print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need for Python 3.6, I've updated the question with your solution but the error now is:

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now it works for Python 3.6